# Objective C - Synthesize property

Tags: objective-c, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prefixing property names with an underscore in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521254/prefixing-property-names-with-an-underscore-in-objective-c)

When synthesizing properties I found out that someone is doing:

```
@synthesize myVar = _myVar;
```

what is "_myVar" and which is the difference with simply doing :

```
@synthesize myVar;
```

Lastly when I should prefer the first solution to the last one?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `_myVar` really is in your example, is the name of the ivar that is backing your property. By default, when you synthesize a property, an ivar of the same name is created for you. So, you can use your property to set your ivar through setter/getter or the `_myVar` to directly access your variable (bypassing KVC/KVO of course).

**EDIT:**
From Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE)

> ...In many cases, when you use a declared property you also synthesize
>   a corresponding instance variable.
>
> Make sure the name of the instance variable concisely describes the
>   attribute stored. Usually, you should not access instance variables
>   directly, instead you should use accessor methods (you do access
>   instance variables directly in init and dealloc methods). To help to
>   signal this, prefix instance variable names with an underscore (_)...

Comment: when should I use the auto-synthetized ivar and when Should I manually set the backing ivars variable manually?

Comment: It's really up to you. Though, it's a common practice in obj-c to prefix ivars with an underscore so to make it clear that you're intentionally accessing directly the ivar. If anyone can think of another reason, I would be glad to be enlightened as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use some existing data member in setter and getter then it can be specify like that.

e.g. @synthesize personName=pName;

by this we can use pName instead of personName as per our convenience.

Answer (score -1):

It the name of the private variable.

Se my answer on an other post: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541716/objective-c-convention-to-prevent-local-declaration-hides-instance-variable-wa/7525730#7525730)

Comment: You mean the instance variable